# Origin of "://" in many URI syntaxes

Tags: url, syntax, history

Anybody knows where the "`://`" or the "`//`" comes from in most URIs syntaxes?
For instance, why isn't it written like "`http:www.example.com`"?

Comment: SO's URL-shortening parser is a real pain in the arse when trying to answer this one :)

Comment: please reopen this question, it is very useful

Comment: [What is the semantics of the double slash following the scheme in a URI?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8870227/1591669)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

a1kmm's answer is good for specific application to URLs, but if you're curious as to the semantic origin of the double slash, take a look at this article:

http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Axioms.html

> It is worth noting that the syntax
>   with the double slash can in fact be
>   extended for use with a triple slash
>   if one wanted to be able to start at
>   any level in a much more complicated
>   hierarchical structure. For example,
>   suppose international telephone
>   numbers were to be extended to cover a
>   planetary code in the future. Then the
>   planetary code could be attached to
>   the front of the international code.
>   The triple slash could introduce the
>   interplanetary code, and the double
>   slash would introduce the
>   international code. Indeed, this is
>   how the double slash came to be: when
>   hierarchical naming schemes such as
>   those in unix file systems was
>   extended to a networks file system on
>   the Apollo domain the extra slash was
>   introduced. Similarly, Microsoft NT
>   networking now uses double backslash
>   in exactly the same way.

Comment: A lot of internet "syntax" is based on the Apollo domain system -- eg the @ symbol in an email address, the fact that a hostname goes "small.medium.big", whereas the unix path goes /big/medium/small. I think Berners-Lee talks about it in his autobiography, Weaving the Web. He even mentions that he thought about going full unix, and having //com/stackoverflow/www/questions/1388194/origin-of-in-many-uri-syntaxes

Comment: @Pod A: so *why* he didn't? (tldr:P) B: any link on what the heck 'the Apollo domain system' is? :) I was trying [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo/Domain) but it contains not the `@`.

Answer (score 7):

The definitive reference on URLs is RFC1738, which came out in December 1994. See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

To quote from the RFC:

> URLs are written in general as
>
>     <scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>

and later on says

> While the syntax for the rest of the URL may vary depending on the
> particular scheme selected, URL schemes that involve the direct use
> of an IP-based protocol to a specified host on the Internet use a
> common syntax for the scheme-specific data:

```
//<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>
```

> Some or all of the parts "<user>:<password>@", ":<password>",
> ":<port>", and "/<url-path>" may be excluded.  The scheme specific
> data start with a double slash "//" to indicate that it complies with
> the common Internet scheme syntax.

Comment: Hmm so this begs the question, why does this "common Internet scheme syntax" require a double slash? (-: