# What is the semantics of the double slash following the scheme in a URI?

Tags: uri, url-scheme, authority

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier, a URI may or may not contain a double slash following the scheme identifier. This makes "urn:issn:1535-3613" a valid URI just as "http://stackoverflow.com".

Is there a strict/formal need to include the double slash or is it optional and in any case, what is the reason/semantics? When answering, please provide a conclusive answer - Don't just report how you browser/library/... handles it.

Comment: A conclusive answer? Do you think an RFC is non-conclusive?

Comment: I'd consider an RFC conclusive. I just seemed to have "overskimmed" the significant section :-|.

Comment: @paxdiablo That's fair—though RFC-3986 has been famously misunderstood and fiercely debated over the years. It's certainly conclusive, but also confusing; I understand Holger wanting justified clarification! :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's in the RFC you linked: If there is a `//`, it means that what follows that is the *authority*. See [Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3). So if the scheme uses an *authority*, it will use the `//` after the colon (either requiring it, if *authority* is required in that scheme, or having it be optional if *authority* is optional in that scheme). `mailto` doesn't use an *authority* in the URI sense, so `mailto` URIs don't include a `//`.

Comment: I don't really see the difference in the domainname in `http://foo@example.org` and `mailto:foo@example.org`. Where is the latter not defined as an authority? I feel that it might just be inconsistent.

Comment: In the first example, foo@ is the userinfo subcomponent in the authority. In the latter, foo@example.org is the path component.

Answer (score 12):

Besides the RFC which thoroughly explains the answer, I thought you might like this quote straight from the [inventor of the World Wide Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee) himself.

> When [Sir Tim Berners-Lee] was asked what he would have done
>   differently, the answer was easy. "I would have got rid of the slash
>   slash after the colon. You don't really need it. It just seemed like a
>   good idea at the time."

Source: http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2014-02/06/tim-berners-lee-reclaim-the-web

Comment: Note that currently double slash allows scheme-relative URLs like `//cdn.example.com`, even if it probably was not an initial intention.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want a "conclusive answer", I think nothing is more conclusive than the official [HTTP RFC document](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (see point 3.2.2 which talks about the HTTP URL scheme).